# C bit shifting odd results past 15 bit shifts leftwise

Tags: c, bit-shift

so I am shifting up a char into a long, then clearing, and doing it again. A shift of 15 makes my machine go wacky, see comment in code. What do you think is causing this.

This machine char 0x00, and long 0x0000 0000

```
    unsigned char temp;
    unsigned long open_code;

    temp = 0x01;
    open_code = open_code | (temp <<1);// open_code = 0x0000 0002 
    open_code = 0;
    //......    
    // 2 - 7    
    //....  
    temp = 0x01;
    open_code = open_code | (temp <<8); // open_code = 0x0000 0100 
    open_code = 0;  
    temp = 0x01;
    open_code = open_code | (temp <<9); // open_code = 0x0000 0200 
    open_code = 0;  
    temp = 0x01;
    open_code = open_code | (temp <<10); // open_code = 0x0000 0400 
    open_code = 0;  
    temp = 0x01;
    open_code = open_code | (temp <<11); // open_code = 0x0000 0800 
    open_code = 0;
    temp =  0x01;
    open_code = open_code | (temp <<12); // open_code = 0x0000 1000
    open_code = 0;  
    temp =  0x01;
    open_code = open_code | (temp <<13); // open_code = 0x0000 2000
    open_code = 0;  
    temp =  0x01;
    open_code = open_code | (temp <<14); // open_code = 0x0000 4000  
    open_code = 0;
    temp =  0x01;
    open_code = open_code | (temp <<15); // open_code = 0xFFFF 8000  !!!!!
    open_code = 0;
    temp =  0x01;
    open_code = open_code | (temp <<16); // open_code = 0x0000 0000  !!!!!
```

Comment: have you tried copy char into a long first, then shifting it?

Comment: Looks perfectly "normal" to me.  Just an interaction of C's various casting rules (which are often inscrutable).

Comment: Zilog Z8 Encore! C-Compiler (microcontroller)The Zilog Z8 Encore! C-Compiler is a freestanding ANSI C compiler (see Freestanding Implementation), complying with the 1989 ISO standard, which is also known as ANSI Standard X3.159-1989 with some deviations, which are described in Deviations from ANSI C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're shifting an `unsigned char` too far and as a result inducing overflow. Try casting it to a `long` *before* shifting, like so:

```
open_code = open_code | (((long)temp) <<15);
```

Comment: ok then the shift is happening inside temp then? That makes sense.

Comment: @user2758: I'm not sure it's accurate to say it's happening _inside_ `temp`. Actually, you might be right, and my answer might be wrong. You might need to have `temp` be a bigger type!

Comment: temp is promoted to an int before the shift operator is executed. The issue is likely related to int being signed but i haven't quite wrapped my head around why.

Comment: @DaveRager: Does that mean my original answer was accurate? I suppose  could just test it...

Comment: @Dan, probably. I'm starting to wonder if ints are 16 bits on this platform. That might explain the sign extension when shift is 15.

Comment: type casting temp to a long open_code = open_code | ((long)temp <<16);

Comment: @DaveRager The type sizes for the basic data types on the Z8 Encore! C-Compiler are as follows:

int
 16 bits
 
short int
 16 bits
 
char
 8 bits
 
long
 32 bits
 
float
 32 bits
 
double
 32 bits

Comment: Personally I would just make `temp` `unsigned int` or `unsigned long` (depending on how much you need to shift them), so to avoid cluttering the code with casts and the "nice" surprises of shifting `signed` types and mixing them with `unsigned` ones.

Comment: @user2758, that definitely explains it. `temp` is promoted to an `int` (16 bits) then shifted giving you `0x8000`. Because it is signed, when it is assigned to open_code, it is sign extended giving you `0xffff8000`. When you shift 16, you overflow the 16 bit integer giving you `0x0000` and then `0x00000000`.